# Wamp Blocking Outside traffic

Tags: apache, wamp

---

Wamp Version:2.5
Windows Version:10
Apache Version:2.4.9

---

Wamp is Green, and its online, and it works when i type localhost, and it work in my local network meaning anyone in my house can access the site , i already port forwarded! but when i try to access my site from outside my network it keeps loading and never works!

---

**Virtual host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName aaess.tk
    ServerAlias www.aaess.tk
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted             <- to allow inet access
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please help and explain why wamp is blocking outside traffic?

Comment: How are you addressing the site from outside the house?

Comment: @RiggsFolly aaess.tk

Comment: Which is pointing to my ip and I already portforwarded

Comment: Have you checked your firewall on the PC running Apache

Comment: Is there anything relevant in your Apache logs both the access log and the error log

Comment: @RiggsFolly no in the access log its just telling me 192.168.1.1 accessed the site thats it

Comment: And the error log?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nothing! its i have cgi setup for python and its warning that its for python 3.5.1 and i have python 3.5.2

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just blocked my firewall and tried http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com, my site  aaess.tk still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sharing a connection with others. Like if you live in an apartment block and the owner has a router that connects to the internet, and each apartment connects their router to the main router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly your ISP is blocking port 80.

#### Simple Test

You could just change your Port Forwarding.

Instead of forwarding router port 80 to PC port 80, just amend the Routers Port Forwarding to forward Router port 8888 to PC's port 80.

Then access the site using `http://aaess.tk:8888`

Using this method you can leave your Virtual Host on port 80.

> It maybe worth trying a few different port numbers, I have knows ISP's to block port 8000 and 8080 as well as these are the most frequently tried alternative port numbers.
>
> Also if you are getting your internet connection via a central connection in an apartment block or compound of some sort. It maybe that you will not find any port that you can use as the central router will be blocking all ports other than port 80.

Comment: i already have that setup, can you try accessing aaess.tk:8080

Comment: No luck I am afraid

Comment: thats the excat reason why i think wamp is blocking the connection

Comment: wana try team viewer?

Comment: If WAMPServer (Apache) was blocking the connection you would see a line in the access or error log (forget which) telling you something like `access blocked due to server configuration`

Comment: If you dont see anything in the apache logs the connection is not getting as far as Apache

Comment: We can try a Team Viewer session of you like. Send the ID and PASSWORD to `riggsfolly@gmail.com`

Comment: so basically , its not a port problem, or apache problem , or firewall problem, so what is it?

Comment: What firewall are you using?

Comment: i sent you the email